# Шаблонная функция, считающая количество элементов массива

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, шаблоны-с++

Функция `foo()` считает кол-во элементов массива. В случае с типом "char" все работает правильно,а "int" - нет.
Код:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>

int foo(T *a)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (*a++)
    {
        i++;
    } return i + 1;
}

int main()
{
    char ch[] = "hellohowareu";
    int ii[] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
    cout << foo(ch) << endl;
    cout << foo(ii) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

з.ы. Функция списана из книжки Страуструпа,только "модернизировал" и добавил шаблон.

Comment: `int ii[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,0 };` Она наверное для строк. Ноль в конце массива добавьте как маркер конца массива

Comment: Все строковые литералы согласно стандарту заканчиваются неявным символом 0 (null-terminator). Функция считает элементы, начиная с начала адреса массива до первого нуля. Со строковыми литералами такое сработает, но с обычными массивами - уже нет.

Comment: да,вы оказались правы) но если нужно постоянно добавлять 0,то для "int" она бесполезна. проще пользоваться стандартной - sizeoff(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])

Comment: @escape проще пользоваться std::size(arr)

Comment: @escape насколько я знаю, такие штуки `sizeoff(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` можно использовать ТОЛЬКО для массивов вида `t arr[] = {t(), t(), t(), t()};`, то есть если у вас будет массив `int* a = new int[5]` - то размер вы уже не вычислите.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Смотрите: она считает

```
while (*a++)
```

количество элементов массива *до первого нулевого*. При инициализации массива символов строковым литералом в массив добавляется завершающий нулевой символ. В массиве `int` этого не делается, так что ваша функция выходит за пределы массива и идет дальше, пока не найдет ноль. Или пока не произойдет что-то неприятное :) - выход за границы массива - это UB, так что произойти может что угодно...

Если очень хочется именно через свой шаблон - то вот вариант:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
size_t foo(const T(&)[N])
{
    return N;
}
```

Но в C++17 такой шаблон уже есть, называется [`size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size).

Answer (score 0):

```
 cout <<  std::distance(std::begin(ii), std::end(ii));
```

Comment: А чего заминусовали-то? Причем молча. Не сказать что очень уж изящное решение, но как вариант годится. Тем более, что исходная функция Страуструпа, что ТС привел, тоже далеко не шедевр.

Comment: минусы просто могут запутать читателей. Можно подумать, что это неправильно. Мне то  не горячо и не холодно от этого...

Comment: Дело-то не в минусах, а в том, что нормальный ответ минусуется молча. Не понравился ответ, ну и напиши что не так. А так вот гадай - то ли он в ответе ошибку углядел, то ли запором мучается и поэтому весь мир ненавидит.

Comment: @freim Регулярное явление, увы. Минусуешь - так поясни, в чем дело. А то вот отминусовали мне сегодня два давно (в 2017 году) принятых вопроса, и пойми, какая-то неточность там имеется, или упомянутая вами причина :)

Comment: @Harry,  это культура, котрая у нас не на высшем уровне. Нужно отнестись серьезно и  к  тому как отвечаешь и к тому, что нужно  написать пояснительный комментарий, прежде чем минусовать(при этом, конечно, изредка могут быть  случаи, когда  все явно и комментарии не нужны) . В данном ответе я поленился написать пояснительный комментарий, а это  плохо.  Бывали случаи, я сам минусовал без комментариев,  потому что лень писать... Буду стараться больше так не поступать, чего и желаю всем остальным